# Concatenation of contiguous blocks of 1's in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a binary sequence `{0,1}` as Pandas DataFrame:
The first column 'a' is the original sequence, and the column 'b' is the desired output. The goal is to concatenate blocks of 1's if the gap (a contiguous sequence of 0's) is larger than some constant k (in this case, k=4).

```
df
     a  b
180  1  1
181  1  1
182  1  1
183  0  0
184  0  0
185  0  0
186  0  0
187  0  0
188  0  0
189  1  1
190  1  1
191  1  1
192  1  1
193  1  1
194  1  1
195  0  **1**
196  0  **1**
197  0  **1**
198  1  1
199  1  1
200  1  1
201  0  **1**
202  1  1
203  1  1
204  1  1
205  1  1
206  1  1
207  1  1
208  1  1
209  1  1
210  1  1
211  0  **1**
212  0  **1**
213  1  1
214  1  1
215  1  1
216  1  1
217  1  1
218  1  1
219  1  1
220  1  1
221  1  1
222  1  1
223  1  1
224  1  1
225  0  **1**
226  1  1
227  1  1
228  1  1
229  0  **1**
230  1  1
231  1  1
232  1  1
233  1  1
234  1  1
235  1  1
236  0  **1**
237  1  1
238  1  1
```

I am studying Pandas and neat pandasian solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Clarification... You want to change the zeros to ones if the block of continuous zeros are smaller than less or equal to 4 in this case right?

Comment: Yes! If there are gaps (with zeros) less than 4, then these gaps should be turned to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
k=4
df['zeros'] = df.groupby(df.a.cumsum()).cumcount()

df2 = df.assign(b=np.logical_or(df.groupby(df.a.cumsum())['zeros'].transform('max').mask(df.a.astype(bool)).le(k).astype(int),df.a).astype(int)).drop('zeros',axis=1)
print(df2)
```

output:

```
     a  b
180  1  1
181  1  1
182  1  1
183  0  0
184  0  0
185  0  0
186  0  0
187  0  0
188  0  0
189  1  1
190  1  1
191  1  1
192  1  1
193  1  1
194  1  1
195  0  1
196  0  1
197  0  1
198  1  1
199  1  1
200  1  1
201  0  1
202  1  1
203  1  1
204  1  1
205  1  1
206  1  1
207  1  1
208  1  1
209  1  1
210  1  1
211  0  1
212  0  1
213  1  1
214  1  1
215  1  1
216  1  1
217  1  1
218  1  1
219  1  1
220  1  1
221  1  1
222  1  1
223  1  1
224  1  1
225  0  1
226  1  1
227  1  1
228  1  1
229  0  1
230  1  1
231  1  1
232  1  1
233  1  1
234  1  1
235  1  1
236  0  1
237  1  1
238  1  1
```